# Automate WhatsApp to Send a Certain Message When a Received Message Includes a Certain Phrase

Tags: python, api, messaging, whatsapp

I am trying to see if it is possible to send a certain message to a group chat on WhatsApp when a message with a certain phrase is received. As an example assume I receive a message "Hello darling can you stop by at the grocery store? I love you". Since this message includes "I love you" I want to respond "Love you baby" automatically. Is this possible? If so how can I achieve my goal? My preferred language is Python.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You should do a web search about it. Modules like`Selenium` or `pywhatkit` can be used depending upon your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has a good python [api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/python) to do this (they only have a free trial but it's a clean way to do what you want to do).
In a web environment the code will run inside a server: the api will send it a [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/python#receive-and-reply-to-messages-from-whatsapp) when a message is received; the program will filter out messages that do not need a reply; then it will send back a message to ones that need a reply.

Another way is to log into whatsapp web using [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) and then building all the logic upon it.

Comment: I am trying to do this on web. If it helps.